# Server compatabile configuration file path reference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an configuration file containing DB details like DB URL(let us keep it as ABC.xml).I am placing it in server.xml(Tomcat) and using JNDI lookup to access it.Since I have to refer this file path in server.xml,I want to make it compatible to windows and linux server.Since the file is placed out of the application
I have to refer it in the server.xml as D:/ABC.xml(for windows) or  ..\..\..\config\ (for Linux).Is there a way to refer this ABC.xml path ,such that I don't 
have to use different formats in different servers.

Please note that this ABC.xml is referred in server.xml of Tomcat so I guess it can't be placed inside the application and can be referred  as an relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like tomcat-user.xml mapped in server.xml

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

and modify

Modify the context.xml file
In /conf/context.xml between  and  add the following for each entry in the JNDI resource list:
" name="jdbc/" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/>
Example

```
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
 <WatchedResource>META-INF/ABC.xml</WatchedResource>
```